# To use my C# client do I need to instal Oracle Client?

Tags: c#, oracle

I have developped a C# client that connects to an Oracle database.

I would like to know please, that if I ship my application, should the user instal Oracle client to use it ? or it will be fine if I just ship with it Oracle.dataaccess.dll file ?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: I once did a project of this kind, we shared a database in the classroom and it worked, but yes, every PC had Oracle installed in it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience. The question is about whether it's required to have multiple oracle licences or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2014/14-mar/o24odp-2147205.html), if you use the Oracle Managed provider you don't need anything else than the provider itself

In that article you could read

> ODP.NET is now available in two flavors. The first, ODP.NET, Unmanaged
>   Driver, contains unmanaged code, meaning that some of the libraries it
>   relies on have been compiled directly to machine code rather than to
>   .NET bytecode. ODP.NET 12.1 introduces the second flavor, ODP.NET,
>   Managed Driver, which is fully managed, meaning that the entire driver
>   and supporting client and networking libraries have been compiled to
>   .NET bytecode and run entirely inside the Common Language Runtime, the
>   .NET virtual machine.

And this is the page where you can [download this provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/utilsoft-086879.html) for free.